# Pandas find cumulative difference across two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm quite new to python and am struggling with this problem. I would like to write a program that allows me, for every value in 'a', to find the cumulative difference of all values above it in 'b', and write it to a new column 'c'. I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 15, 25, 30, 10, 20], 'b': [ 10, 'na', 20, 'na', 30, 10]})
        
Index|   a  |  b  |
0    |  10  | 10  |
1    |  15  | na  |
2    |  25  | 20  |
3    |  30  | na  |
4    |  10  | 30  |
5    |  20  | 10  |
```

I want to skip nas. Items in b are values above zero, so if it makes it easier, I can change nas to 0 and still skip all 0 values.

Ideally, I would expect a new column `df['c']` like this:

```
Index|   a  |  b  |  c  |
0    |  10  | 10  |  0  |  # 10-10 = 0
1    |  15  | na  |  5  |  # 15 - 10 = 5
2    |  25  | 20  | 20  |  # (25-20) + (25-10) = 5 + 15 = 20
3    |  30  | na  | 30  |  # (30-20) + (30-10) = 10+20 = 30
4    |  10  | 30  |-30  |  # (10-30) + (10-20) + (10-10) = -30
5    |  20  | 10  | 10  |  # (20-10) + (20-30) + (20-20) + (20-10) = 10
```

I've tried using  `df['c] = cumsum(df['a'] - df['b'])` , but it doesn't get the job done -- I need to subtract  `df['a']` from its corresponding value in `df['b']`, as well as all the values above it in column df['b'].

I've also tried  `df['c] = df['a'] * len(df['b'].unique()) - cumsum(df['b'])` , but the problem with this is that `len(df['b'].unique())` is always the same length (doesn't change based on index), and numbers in b aren't necessarily unique (for example, 10 appears at indexes 0 and 5).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Also this is my first time using Stack Overflow; if there's anything unclear about my formatting or question please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close! You appropriately refactored the math in your second approach, however the tricky part is how to properly account for `NaN` via this snippet `len(df['b'].unique())`. You can create a mask where `NaN` values = 0 and non `NaN` values = 1 and then cumulatively sum those values to obtain the proper coefficients for multiplication:

```
df["c"] = (df["a"] * df["b"].notnull().cumsum()) - df["b"].fillna(0).cumsum()

print(df)
    a     b     c
0  10  10.0   0.0
1  15   NaN   5.0
2  25  20.0  20.0
3  30   NaN  30.0
4  10  30.0 -30.0
5  20  10.0  10.0
```

To demistify the approach of resolving the coefficients little, here's an intermediate output:

```
>>> df["b"].notnull().cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
Name: b, dtype: int64
```